# IEEE 1394 4 Pin Male compatibility (?)

Tags: macbook-pro, compatibility, firewire

Is a IEEE 1394 4 Pin Male connector compatible with the FireWire port on a Macbook Pro 15" mid-2012 non-retina (MBP 9,1) ?

Comment: Unless I'm totally mistaken, Firewire **is** IEEE 1394. Which problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @nohillside: The Mac has firewire 800 (9 pin). Older Macs have firewire 400 (6 pin). The OP has firewire 400 (4 pin). I think this might be firewire 400 without power delivery.

Comment: From a quick Google of pictures, it looks like it's a completely different shape from the FW800 port.

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks, missed the part about this being about the physical port.

Comment: Jet Hyper: The firewire 800 offered by the Mac should be backward compatible with your firewire 400 (IEEE 1394 4 Pin) device, as explained in [this article](https://www.lacie.com/support/kb/firewire-questions-answers-007272en/#:~:text=Will%20FireWire%20800%20Devices%20Work,cable%20must%20be%20used%2C%20though.).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can ascertain, the 4-pin IEEE 1394 is the one on the left hand side of this picture -- small, rectangular, with an indent at the top.

The Mac's FW800 port fits the plug on the right hand side.

The picture show both ends of one cable, so you can certainly buy a cable of this kind that will join the 4-pin socket on some other device to your Mac.

[image]